# Why my discord bot spams messages by adding the following code?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

I am coding a basic moderation bot for Discord in `discord.js`. But by adding the following code for replying "Hello!" everytime someone sends message from the list, the bot spams a lot of "Hello!" messages in the channel.

```js
client.on("message", async message =>{
  if (message.content == "Hi" || message.content == "hi" || message.content == "hello" || message.content == "Hello" || message.content == "hi!" || message.content == "Hi!" || message.content == "Hello!" || message.content == "hello!")
  {
    message.channel.send(`Hello!`)
  }
});
```

Can someone explain why does this happen and provide a solution to it? I tried to search on the web but was not able to phrase the question properly, so I got no answers.

P.S.: I am still learning JavaScript and I am coding this in replit.com, if that matters!

Comment: Think through the event loop you've constructed: when the `client` sees a `message`, it inspects the content of `message`. When it encounters a string in said `message` that matches one of the strings you provided here, it will send a message `"Hello!"` in the same channel. That message *it* sends triggers yet *another* `message` event, which your code runs again and does *the same thing*, because the message your bot sent (`"Hello!"`) is contained in your conditional. The solution is to check the `message`'s author to ensure it's not the bot before sending a reply to itself inadvertently.

Comment: Oh yes! I didn't think of that! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As esqew pointed out in their comment, your bot is stuck in an event loop of replying to its own message. An easy way to deal with this problem would be to ignore messages from either all bots, or just the bot's own messages, as demonstrated below.

```js
client.on("message", async message => {
    // Method A: Ignore all Bots
    if(message.author.bot) return;

    // Method B: Ignore self only
    if(message.author.id == client.user.id) return;

    // Insert rest of event code here, etc...
});
```

See [`User.bot`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/User?scrollTo=bot) (Discord.js Docs)